# Test don't run when i run maven test with appium java project

Tags: java, android, maven, testing, appium

i would see and test appium for my project and i finish setup a new maven project with appium and cucumber, but i have this issue:
when i run maven test i see ever zero test run and i don't understand where is the issue.

JDK installed on my local machine:JDK-15
path of jdk bin and maven bin is in my windows path variable

This is my POM file: https://github.com/silv3ri0/test-appium-java/blob/master/com.qa/pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>qa.mobile</groupId>
  <artifactId>com.qa</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.version>3.6.0</maven.compiler.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
  
  <dependencies>
  
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>7.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.7.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>6.6.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-testng -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    
</dependencies>
  
  <build>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/java</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Werror</compilerArgument>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
            </plugin>            
        </plugins>        
    </build>  
</project>
```

MyRunnerTestClass: https://github.com/silv3ri0/test-appium-java/blob/master/com.qa/src/test/java/com/qa/runners/MyRunnerTest.java

```
    package com.qa.runners;
    
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;
    
    import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
    import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
    import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions.SnippetType;
    
    //@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
    @CucumberOptions(plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber", "summary"}
                                ,features = {"src/test/resources"}
                                ,glue = {"com.qa.stepdef"}/*tags = {"@appium"}*/)
   @Test
    public class MyRunnerTest {
    
    }
```

StedefClass: https://github.com/silv3ri0/test-appium-java/blob/master/com.qa/src/test/java/com/qa/stepdef/MissguidedStepDef.java

```
package com.qa.stepdef;

import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.Assert;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Then;
import io.cucumber.java.en.When;
import utility.Hook;

public class MissguidedStepDef {
    
    private AppiumDriver driver;
    
    public MissguidedStepDef() {
        this.driver = (AppiumDriver) Hook.getDriver();
    }
    
    @Given("^i navigate the shop$")
    public void iNavigateTheShop() {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        Assert.assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@text='Accessibility']")).isDisplayed());
        
    }
```

Hooks Class: https://github.com/silv3ri0/test-appium-java/blob/master/com.qa/src/test/java/utility/Hook.java

```
package utility;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.cucumber.java.After;
import io.cucumber.java.Before;

public class Hook {

    private static AppiumDriver driver;
    
    @Before
    public void setUpAppium() throws MalformedURLException
    {
        DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "11");
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "any device name");
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability("automationName", "UiAutomator2");
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability("avd", "Pixel_3_API_30");
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.poqstudio.app.platform.missguided");
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.poqstudio.app.platform.presentation.countrySwitcher.view.CountrySwitcherSelectCountryActivity");
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability("app", "C:\\projectappium/Missguided_v14.3.0.1_apkpure.com.apk");

        URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");

        driver = new AndroidDriver(url, desiredCapabilities);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        
        
    }
    
    @After
    public void tearDown()
    {
        driver.quit();
    }
    
    public static WebDriver getDriver()
    {
        return driver;
    }}
```

Feature file: https://github.com/silv3ri0/test-appium-java/blob/master/com.qa/src/test/resources/AddToBag.feature

```
Feature: Test add to bag
Scenario: Show register form after add to bag
    Given i navigate the shop
    And select clearence category
    And select seven item from search result
    And add to bag item
    When go to the select pay 
    Then sign in is displayed
```

Can someone help me? For me for now it's important to verify at least first step of my feature file working fine.

When i say test don't run i mean that when i click on maven test on my pom file i see this result in the console:

```
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for qa.mobile:com.qa:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin is missing. @ line 77, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --------------------------< qa.mobile:com.qa >--------------------------
[INFO] Building com.qa 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ com.qa ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ com.qa ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ com.qa ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ com.qa ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 3 source files to C:\Users\giancristofaros\eclipse-workspace\com.qa\target\test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ com.qa ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\Users\giancristofaros\eclipse-workspace\com.qa\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.qa.runners.MyRunnerTest
Configuring TestNG with: org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.conf.TestNG652Configurator@1ae369b7
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.31 sec

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  9.971 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-09-30T16:32:38+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Any idea about this issue?

Thanks in advance,
Silverio

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Linking to lots of files will probably lead to people skipping your question. It's best to include small code snippets (the minimal amount needed!) in the text you're posting. You can use formatting in the code editor to make it appear neatly in your question. Additionally, please specify what you mean by "tests don't run". (e.g. they don't start because they can't be found, or because they crash, or some _specific_ error etc.)

Comment: Hello @KenVanHoeylandt thanks for the feedback, i fix it all point.

Answer (score 0):

Maven Surefire plugin isn't configured properly

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/Tests*.java</include>
                    <include>**/**/*Tests.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

maven surefire gets the files which contain Test or Tests in the filename. You had included your test class, but not in the right place.

Comment: Hi Alin, thanks for your feedback,i try to edit my pom.xml with this code but the issue still persist.
[code]
<build>
   <plugins>
     <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>2.22.2</version>
         <configuration>
         <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
         <includes>
          <include>**/Test*.java</include>
              <include>**/**/*Test.java</include>
             </includes>
          </configuration>
  </plugin>
 </plugins>        
</build>  
[code]